# Ant zipfileset rename file

Tags: ant, rename

I would like to include file to `zipfileset` but rename it as well

e.g.

```
<zipfileset dir="${basedir}/test/target"   prefix="webapps">
    <include name="test*.war"/>
</zipfileset>
```

but want to change name from `test.war` to `sample.war`

how to achieve this ? thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can probably do what you want using a [`mappedresources` resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources).
This 'worked for me' in a basic test (one input war called `test1.war`):

```
<mappedresources id="mapped.zfs">
    <zipfileset dir="${basedir}/test/target">
        <include name="test*.war"/>
    </zipfileset>
    <globmapper from="test*" to="webapps/sample*" />
</mappedresources>

<zip destfile="eg.zip">
    <resources refid="mapped.zfs" />
</zip>

% unzip -l eg.zip 
Archive:  eg.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  11-27-2012 00:19   webapps/
     1423  11-27-2012 00:16   webapps/sample1.war
---------                     -------
     1423                     2 files
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, I'd go for 2 steps approach.

Either rename and add:

```
<move file="${basedir}/test/target/test.war" tofile="${basedir}/test/target/sample.war"/>
<zipfileset dir="${basedir}/test/target"   prefix="webapps">
    <include name="sample*.war"/>
</zipfileset>
```

or copy and add (if you need both):

```
<copy file="${basedir}/test/target/test.war" tofile="${basedir}/test/target/sample.war"/>
<zipfileset dir="${basedir}/test/target"   prefix="webapps">
    <include name="sample*.war"/>
</zipfileset>
```

Answer (score 1):

martin clayton's answer worked for me. I was also able to do it all in one element (as children):

```
<zip destfile="eg.zip">
  <mappedresources>
    <zipfileset file="test*.war"/>
    <globmapper from="test*" to="webapps/sample*" />
  </mappedresources>
  <!-- additional file-sets and resources may be listed here -->
</zip>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to solution mentioned by peter, if you do not want to retain 2 copies of the same file... you can remove the copied one...

```
<copy file="${basedir}/test/target/test.war" tofile="${basedir}/test/target/sample.war"/>
<zipfileset dir="${basedir}/test/target"   prefix="webapps">
    <include name="sample*.war"/>
</zipfileset>
<delete file="${basedir}/test/target/sample.war"/>
```

Now you would not have duplicate copy of test.war.